# angular httpservice: issue with connecting Json file

Tags: angular-http

I'm new to angular4 and trying to build a Database connection with JSON and angular app. But I'm facing following issue in browse while refreshing the app.

Failed to compile.

```
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/index.js
```

> Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\angproj\Secondproj\node_modules\rxjs_esm5\index.js'

Below is my code. How to fix it?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private http: Http) { }
   httpdata;
   ngOnInit() {
      this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
      map(
         (response) => response.json()
      ).
      subscribe(
         (data) => {this.displaydata(data);}
      )
   }
   displaydata(data) {this.httpdata = data;}
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      HttpModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs due to name mismatch. Check this part of your code and see if there is an error in URL, the variable name.

```
`export class AppComponent {
   constructor(private http: Http) { }
   httpdata;
   ngOnInit() {
      this.http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
      map(
         (response) => response.json()
      ).
      subscribe(
         (data) => {this.displaydata(data);}
      )
   }
   displaydata(data) {this.httpdata = data;}
}

`
```